# Android auto complete for edit text (show hint after cursor)

Tags: android

I want to make a widget that gives hints for auto completion, something like in iphones

For example when I enter

Hello Wo|

It is giving a hint like that

Hello Wo|rld

rld is slightly lighter shade, when you click on text it auto completes to Hello World.

Is this possible for android widgets? I know about AutoCompleteTextView but it looks quite bad on smaller screens and for smaller text fields. If it is not possible in android, do you guys know a widget/library that supports it?

Comment: Nice thought. I'll try it

Comment: You may be interested in Roman Nurik's [Chips Text Fields](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/chips-text-fields/) library. I can't recall whether it does suggestions out of the box, but it could be an interesting starting point, or at least a place to pick up some ideas.